# How do I test an html button within a React prop?

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

I have the following code (simplified for understanding):

```
class ClassA extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    clicked: true
  }
}

render () {
 return (
   <Snackbar
     clicked={this.state.clicked}
     message={
       <div> This is the message </div>
     }
     action={[
       <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={functionCall}>
         Go
       </Button>
     ]}
   />
 );
}
```

How do I test the  element? I have tried shallowing ClassA, then shallowing Snackbar, but I am still unable to call a `.simulate('click')` on the button.

Basically, how do you shallow/simulate upon a code piece that is passed as a prop to a higher node?

Comment: the capital B in ```Button``` would suggest it's not a native button. Maybe you need to locate and click the native button...

Comment: No, it is not a native button. I can't even access the prop though for clicking. An onClick should still trigger on a .simulate('click') right?

Comment: I'm not sure about that, as onClick - per se - is a naming convention. Not sure about enzyme, the vanilla react shallow renderer allows ```shallowElement.props.myProp.mySubProp...```

Comment: How did you try? Provide your test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to test the button which is passed as a prop to the Snackbar component, you would need to get the prop to Snackbar and then shallow mount the actions before simulating the click, since it will only work on the mounted component and not a prop

```
const component = shallow(<ClassA />);
const SnackbarAction = component.find(Snackbar).prop('action')[0];
const button = shallow(SnackbarAction);
button.simulate('click');
```

Comment: That worked! The problem was that I was not using the array caller, which isn't needed for calling shallowed objects, but is for props. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to have helped

Answer (score 0):

Try the following piece of code where we access a prop from shallow mounted wrapper.

```
const wrapper = shallow(<ClassA />);
wrapper.find('Snackbar').prop('action')[0].simulate('click');
```

If this doesn't work you can try

```
wrapper.find('Snackbar').prop('action')[0].prop('onClick')();
```